# Finding median using pivot table in Excel using two filtered columns

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, median

I have column A for Job Type.
I have column B for Experience Range.
I have column C for salary.
These are in a sheet named 'Data'.

I have created a pivot table with Job Type as rows and Experience Range as columns. (in another sheet)

I want to find median for each cell in the Pivot Table.

How do I do that?

e.g. how do I find the median of Salary for all 'Stage Manager' (cell A2) with 'less than 2 years' (cell B1) experience?

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you've no doubt discovered, the *median* isn't listed on the grouping options (sum, min, max, count, etc).

There doesn't appear to be a direct way around the problem; however, you may be able to hack your way around it by [adding custom a formula inside the table](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html). Then use the [*median()* function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelstatisticalfunctions/ss/Finding-Average-Values-with-Excels-AVERAGE-Function.htm) in the formula.

Another approach is abandon pivot tables and [use array formulas instead](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/12317/How-to-Create-the-Elusive-Pivot-Table-With-Medians-Excel-Tip.aspx).

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks for the response.
I was able to figure out an array formula when I am filtering along only column A:
=MEDIAN(IF('DATA'!A:A=A2,'DATA'!C:C))

Although, I cannot figure out a way to filter across two columns.

If you could help me out with this, that would be great.

Thanks! :)

Comment: The AND() and OR() functions will be helpful for multi-cloumn filtering.  http://www.bluemoosetech.com/microsoft-excel-functions.php?jid=19&

Comment: I tried that. The AND() function returns a TRUE/FALSE value. It does not give me the intersection of two data sets, which I need.

Comment: Nested IFs worked! Thanks a lot for the help, Raymond! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` for and and `+` for or. `FALSE` is coded as `0` and `TRUE` as `1`.

1. `0*1 = 1`, so if only one condition is met it will be `FALSE`(`AND`)
2. `1+0` or `1+1 is >0`, so if only one condition is met, it will still be `>0` (`OR`)

You can use this fact to do a test as to whether your condition is >0 and then transform your array, so that if the condition is true, the array is the array but otherwise it equal  . This will basically eliminate all rows where the conditions are not met (making them count as blank in any array formula)

You can use this tick for a large number of `AND` and `OR` conditions.

If you use name manager to name your arrays, then you can very easily vary conditions very fast and create a simulated pivot table.

You can then use the aggregate function to ignore hidden rows (e.g. aggregate can calculate median, percentiles and other stuff), and then the filter function can effectively work as a pivot filter.

I usually make my first column a test column that tests if a row is hidden or not and returns 1 if visible and 0 otherwise. Then I build that condition into my condition stack to act as an additional AND switch. This means suddenly your formulas react to the filter to only consider values that are filtered in.

This stuff is really great to do multi-conditional calculations on a large amount of data without the need to manually calculate after each filter - the calculations happen on the fly, as you filter!

Calculations can take 3-5 seconds depending on how many conditions you have and the size of your raw data, so not quite as fast as a pivot table, but very convenient.